# How to keep an external hard drive spinning?

Tags: external-hdd

I have an external USB hard drive plugged in, and after a few minutes, when there's been no activity against it, it automatically spins down, stops, and is unmounted. Is there a way to keep it spinning so I don't lose the mount?

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean lose the mount?  Just because it spins down doesn't mean the mount goes away.

Comment: Is this a feature of your external drive? Specifying the type might help?

Comment: I can't see why it would auto-unmount in this situation but I'm interested to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been looking for that answer for a Seagate  FreeAgent drive, the 2 answers I found were 1) use the Seagate utility on a Windows machine to disable auto-spindown, or [this page](http://zhigang.org/blog/seagate-freeagent-auto-spindown-under-linux/) which explains how to do the same on Linux using sdparm. (but as psusi pointed out, when the drive goes into auto-spindown it shouldn't unmount, at least on recent kernels.

Comment: What I mean by "losing the mount" is that if I do a:  cd /media/wd20/ and then sit there until it spins down, when doing a "ls" from that same point gives me an input/output error. Doing a "cd -" "cd -" to come back after that solves the problem when the disk spins up again.

Comment: Okay so it sounds more like timing-out rather than unmounting.  I've seen something similar on Xubuntu opening Thunar on a spun-down drive, though the window opens and the drive spins up almost immediately after the error.  Never got it in Ubuntu with Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to make it work now, you can set up a loop to touch a file every 30 seconds:

```
while true; do
    touch /media/disk/.tempfile
    sleep 15
done
```

One way to use this is to make a bash file with that script and make another one containing:

```
screen -mdS "some name for the screen" "name of the bash file that you created earlier"
```

For example: `screen -mdS spin spin.sh`

That way you can close the ssh session without ending the script.